# VB.NET Folder location

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

My program uses some external programs that i included in the Files folder.

In my code im reffering to Files/external_program.exe Windows Vista & Windows 7 knows how to handle this and starts the program on the same location as my program in the Files folder.

But Xp doesnt know where it is, and Windows XP will think im reffering to the C:\Files folder. So im getting an error and the app crashes.

How can i fix this? so windows xp will know that i'm reffering to the Files folder on the same location as my program.

Comment: How are you starting the external programs? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out application.startuppath

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx

```
dim progdir as string=application.startuppath & "\files\externalexe.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

The current working directory can be accessed via [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx). I'd also advice to always use the [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) function to join paths, because it already deals with any edge cases you might encounter.

```
Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Files\external_program.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks will try this out when i get home.

Answer (score 0):

Please add application.path before the path of the location.